# Stacked chart from list data

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a `list` with **Teams** & **Status** columns.

I'm trying to create a **stacked chart** grouping by team. But for some reason its not working.

Is there a work-around for this?

[image]

Comment: Please tell us what method you have tried to create chart?

Comment: Maybe you can take a look into http://www.chartjs.org/ I am using that for building charts

Comment: Could you also explain how the chart should look like?

Comment: Hi Mark, I have tried to use sharepoint charts linking to lists directly, tried creating a webpart and linking to that.. 'Connect to Excel Services' is not activated in my organisation..

I actually tried to get work done by jquery and google charts.. but I can only get total number of status per team but was not able to get separate count of status. i.e., Open, Closed & In Progress

Comment: Hi Patrick, I have added expected chart

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, I find the SharePoint charting feature very lacking and overly complicated for most purposes.

Whenever I want to create charts about SharePoint list/library data I use this approach:

- Create a list/library view that contains all the relevant data without any grouping
- export the view to Excel
- use Excel Pivot Tables or custom Excel charts to group, slice and dice the date
- Add Excel Pivot Slicers to the dashboard so users can slice and dice what they need
- save the Excel file in a document library and give folks read access. Configure the data connection to refresh on open.
- teach people to refresh pivot charts / tables

I find that almost all users feel mightily enabled with such a solution. They can refresh data (you can provide a button that triggers VBA, or auto refresh on open), and they can use the slicers to hone in on the aspects they want to see.

This is self-service BI at the most basic level, with just a SharePoint list and an Excel file.

Comment: I actually tried to use 'Connect to Excel Services' option, but it seems that it is not active in my organisation..

So looking out for other option